# SD[which.min()] vs. SD[min()]

Tags: r, data.table

why they have different results?

I thought that the two objects point to the minimum value of Petal.Length equally, don't they?

```
iris_dt <- as.data.table(iris)

x1 <- iris_dt[, .SD[which.min(Petal.Length)], by = Species] 
x2 <- iris_dt[, .SD[min(Petal.Length)], by = Species] 

identical(x1, x2)
# FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check the documentation for `min()` and `which.min()`. These two functions have a different purpose. While `min()` gives you the actual minimum value, `which.min()` on the other hand returns a vector of indices where the minimum values are located. So, it works as designed.